# The `file` command correctly identifies my LUKS device but the kernel doesn't see it

Tags: linux, luks, block-device, cryptsetup, uuid

I recently created a LUKS2 device with a native `--offset` of 4MiB. The `file` command correctly identifies the device and lists its UUID, but it is neither auto-opened at boot nor visible in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/...` (even after `update-initramfs`).

Manually running `cryptsetup open` works as expected but `cryptdisks_start` fails to open it. It is specified with `UUID=` in `/etc/crypttab` like my other devices. Using the "parent" block device path instead of its UUID works.

Inspection with `xxd` shows the correct magic number ("LUKS" at offset 0) and the header starting at the same offset as my other LUKS2 devices (which *are* correctly detected). Why is this device failing to be detected? What can I do to allow me to open it via its UUID?

Comment: What does `blkid /dev/the-block-device` return?

Comment: `udevadm info /dev/the-block-device` might also give some clues.

Comment: Is the encrypted partition formatted (with a filesystem e.g. `ext4`)? Perhaps some mechanism tests for that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `blkid /dev/...` returns `/dev/...: TYPE="jmicron_raid_member"`. Some of my drives are connected via a PCIe SATA card, but so are other LUKS2 devices that work correctly.

Comment: @Ned64 The encrypted partition is formatted with BTRFS but that really shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: If it's meant to be *jmicron raid member*, it shouldn't be accessed directly. If it's not, you should probably try and remove the signature that makes it being detected as such.

Comment: See also [ext4 filesystem wrongly detected as jmicron\_raid\_member](//askubuntu.com/a/249612)

Comment: Perhaps posting the relevant part of `lsblk` (ideally after `cryptsetup open`) would make it easier to understand your setup.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `wipefs` was able to find the "jmicron" signature and erasing it seems to have fixed my problem. If you post your comments as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: What a strange problem to have, though. The encrypted partition sits on top of an LVM volume whose end (where the "jmicron" signature was) is nowhere near the end of the disk; I have no idea how that signature got there. And I guess `file` doesn't check the ends of devices even though that signature had the highest priority...

Comment: @ATLief, it's enough for the 512th last byte to be `J` and 511th last `M` for it to be detected as such. So it could just be an accident (one chance in every 65536 for random data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, the kernel here is not at fault. The only kernel's involvement here is with the `dmcrypt` device mapper device configured by `cryptsetup`.

`cryptsetup` is able to configure the device mapper device based on the metadata as stored on the block device so is not at fault either.

The fact that there's no `/dev/disk/by-uuid` entry for the LUKS device stored there  points at `udev` or whatever is responsible to discovering LUKS devices (see also the output of `udevadm info /dev/the-block-device`).

`udev` uses `blkid` (well, the builtin version see rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules` on Debian for instance) to find out about those.

In your case, `blkid` reports *`TYPE="jmicron_raid_member"`*. If it's a RAID array member, it shouldn't be accessed  directly, so `blkid` is right not to try and report what may be stored inside.

If it's not meant to be a *jmicron_raid_member*, then maybe it just happens to still contain the signature for some RAID configuration, for instance because the SSD used to be connected to a PC with ATA Mode set to RAID instead of AHCI in the BIOS (and you forgot to run `blkdiscard` before reusing it). Or maybe the 512th last byte happens to be `J` and 511th `M` by accident.

For `blkid`  to stop detecting it as a `jmicron_raid_member` if you're sure it's not meant to be and the last 512-byte unit is otherwise not in use by anything, you'd need to wipe the RAID signature, which for jmraid is apparently [found in the last 512 byte unit of the block device](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/libblkid/src/superblocks/jmicron_raid.c#L39), either by hand with something like:

```
size=$(blockdev --getsize -- "$dev") &&
  dd if=/dev/zero of="$dev" seek="$((size - 1))" count=1
```

Or using `util-linux`' `wipefs`:

```
wipefs -t jmicron_raid_member -- "$dev"
```

to list the signature.

```
wipefs -a -t jmicron_raid_member -n -- "$dev"
```

To show what it would erase.

```
wipefs -a -t jmicron_raid_member -- "$dev"
```

To erase.